# how can I trigger a function before publish/update a product in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get a function that gets some info right before save in the database when user publish or updates a product of woocommerce (in wordpress)

So far, Ive found this

```
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'method' );
```

But seems like it is triggered when users enters to create a new product, but I can save it and all without calling this function

Is there any function to do this or any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is your solution:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_product_update' );

function my_product_update( $post ) {
    if($post->post_type == "product"){
         $pid=$post->ID;
         //your code
    }
}
```

Because I think WooCommerce don`t have default hook for this action.